# Display html page in asp.net

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, treeview

I have few html pages in a directory and from ASP .NET web page I would want to read the files and display the files dynamically. In the asp.net i have a tree view control on the left with different options which corresponds to the files. On clicking any particular menu item, i would want to read the contents of the corresponding file and display it in a placeholder on the right side of the page. Can you please let me know how this can be done.

Comment: Simply read file and put content in asp:Literal ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a div on the right side in which you show the html page using [jQuery load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) like:

```
$("#mydiv").load("myfile.html");
```

Comment: I am not completely aware of JQuery. anyways will check it and will get back... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a iframe and add the iframe to your page (you can style the iframe pretty much like a div)

```
<body>
    <iframe src="mypage.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi... When i used frameset or iframe, the page loads up blank without any contents. I have used it in the below way.
<html>
    <frameset>
        <frame src="D:\Sitel-Test-1.htm">
        </frame>
    </frameset>
</html>

The HTML page is not empty.. :( and has quite a lot of contents in it

Comment: <body>
        <iframe width="100%" height="600px" scrolling="no" src="D:\MyPage1.htm"></iframe>
    </body>


This code as well loads a blank page with a frame border but the contents are empty

Comment: drag the page to a browser and copy the URL that should be the absolute path. and that should work, you might want to make content of the page fit the window of the iframe as the content of the page might be outside of the iframe if you diabled the scroll bars.

If you check the source code of the content of the iframe you will see the the content is there.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a `CssClass` property with some class to the menu item. On client side find the element using that class and attach click event handler to it.

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" CssClass="menuItem" Text="Download" Value="Download"/>
```

Js

```
$('.menuItem').click(function(ev){
     var href=$(this).attr('href')
     $("#mydiv").load(href);
    //prevent follow of link
      ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Note that the content place holder id is **mydiv** which can change if you are using `master page` or user controls.

So you can use the "ClientId" to "static" or put a class and use it.

Rather than using a content place holder you can simply use a `div` and give it an `id` and use that.